# Error after updating wamp PHP version to 8.0.7

Tags: php, wampserver

I tried to updated the PHP version but now I have this errors:

**In localhost page:**

> Warning: include(wamplangues/index_english.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 94
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'wamplangues/index_english.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 94

**In phpMyAdmin:**

> Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.8.5\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php on line 615

**The modifications in php.ini**

```
extension_dir = C:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.0.7/ext

 upload_tmp_dir =  C:/wamp64/tmp

 error_log =  C:/wamp64/tmp

; 
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=ffi
extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd
extension=gettext
extension=gmp
extension=intl
extension=imap
extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif
; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=oci8_19  ; Use with Oracle Database 19 Instant Client
extension=odbc
extension=openssl
extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_oci
extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

extension=soap
extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xsl

;zend_extension=opcache
```

Comment: It seems you are using some old version of WAMP server that is not compatible with PHP 8

Comment: I have to download the new version?

Comment: It seems like it. phpmyadmin 4.8.5 is quite old

Comment: But what about my projects?

Comment: What about them? They don't depend on the version of the wamp server. Make sure you do a back up of your projects and your database before you uprade the server

Comment: Btw when i delete the version that i did install the wamp icon become orange i don't why

Comment: Check the error logs. If one of the components cannot start then it will be orange

Comment: I don't know what i should do now, should i just install the new wamp server?

Comment: If your application is not ready to work with PHP 8, it is not ready. Why not resolve the given errors? As you haven't shared the code that triggers the problem, it's impossible to tell you how to fix the code

Answer (score 1):

I did solve the errors by installing the new version of wamp server but i didn't upgrade the php version (it's not necessary any more for me), but if anyone wants to check this url:

[Here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,159568)

After trying to upgrade php version i had many errors, even if i did delete the version the errors stayed the same (in the error log) as a result the wamp server icon turned orange and stayed in that way so i had no choice but to update wamp.
So if anyone have an old wamp version do not try to uprade to php version 8, save your  project and your data base somewhere else and update wamp.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it, instead of linking to external ressources. How did installing a new version of WAMP help to resolve the errors with your application?